Reverse engineering a Bluetooth smart lock (Aqara N200)
I have been working reverse engineering a Aqara N200 as I'd like to now control it in Home Assistant rather than just near the lock with the Mi Home app, my plan is to use a ESP32 running ESPHome to communicate with it.
I've successfully captured the Bluetooth packets using a Google Pixel 6 with Bluetooth HCI Snoop feature in Developer options. I managed to find what I think is the correct packet by doing multiple captures and unlocking the door 3 and 5 times and filtering for the packet using btatt.opcode == 0x12 I am now at loss since the value for all 8 packets are different and I'm not sure how they are generated.
These are the Values of the 8 packets
0700cdec690302

0d00866d396b9b

11005b56ae6119

16001b9e831efd

1b00c3e9628037

0600e0c02ef088

0d00399b1eab25

I'm pretty new to reverse engineering and have learnt a lot at a loss at this bit but I'm trying my best.
Update:
I was able to use frida.re to see values of the packets being sent using this script.
Java.perform(function() {
    // Define the UUIDs you're interested in
    var targetUUIDs = [
        '00001001-0065-6c62-2e74-6f696d2e696d'
    ];

    // Function to convert byte array to hex string
    function bytesToHex(bytes) {
        var hex = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            hex.push(('0' + (bytes[i] & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2));
        }
        return hex.join('');
    }

    // Hook the writeCharacteristic method of BluetoothGatt
    var BluetoothGatt = Java.use('android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt');
    BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic.overload('android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic').implementation = function(characteristic) {
        // Extract UUID and value
        var uuid = characteristic.getUuid().toString();
        var value = characteristic.getValue();

        // Check if UUID is in the list of target UUIDs
        if (targetUUIDs.includes(uuid)) {
            var hexValue = bytesToHex(value);

            console.log('writeCharacteristic called');
            console.log('Characteristic UUID: ' + uuid);
            console.log('Characteristic Value (hex): ' + hexValue);
            
            // Print stack trace
            var stackTrace = Java.use('java.lang.Thread').currentThread().getStackTrace();
            stackTrace.forEach(function(element) {
                console.log(element.toString());
            });
        }
        
        return this.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
    };
});

Which outputs this when I unlock the lock using the app.
writeCharacteristic called
Characteristic UUID: 00001001-0065-6c62-2e74-6f696d2e696d
Characteristic Value (hex): 1a00b793f92f48
dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1841)
android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(Native Method)
_m_j.r00.writeCharacteristic(SourceFile:98)
_m_j.p50.writeCharacteristic(Unknown Source:2)
_m_j.k90.OooO0Oo(SourceFile:25)
_m_j.p50.process(SourceFile:69)
_m_j.c00.handleMessage(SourceFile:34)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:85)
_m_j.vr6.run(SourceFile:16)

I pulled the APK from my Pixel using ADB and decompiled it using JADX. I'm currently having trouble finding where the packet is created

If you have an Android HCI Snoop protocol you have an app that creates those packets. Decompile the app and you may be able to get the algorithm how the packets are generated (or at least get an idea what is involved).

I’m not sure how well that would work since the Mi Home app supports a lot more than just this lock so I’d imagine that it would be hard to find.

If you have a rooted device and the app is a Java/Kotlin app finding the method can be done using https://frida.re. Hook BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic and print the current stack trace in the hook. Then you will see where the write request is coming from and hopefully this is also the lace where the packet data is built.

Thanks for pointing me towards thoses.
